# Accidentally changed my Windows 10 partition and now wont boot into windows

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have a windows 10/linux mint dual installation on my laptop.

Yesterday I was trying to reduce the size of my windows 10 partition to create a separate ext4 partition to use with my linux installation. I thought I had properly shut down windows, but it must have still been in suspend mode when i used GParted to shrink the windows partition and create the new partition.

Now when i try to boot into windows it says it encountered a problem and needs to restart, then when it resets it goes into the automatic repair screen.

When i press "advanced options", nothing works, even if i try to reset the PC, it just says "there was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made".

Can anyone suggest anything i can do to help fix it? I would prefer not to have to wipe the whole partition, because there are files on there that i would like to keep, but if i absolutely have to then i can. So long as it wont wipe my linux partition as well..

**UPDATE:**

I tried to do a full reset, wiping everything on that partition and it just says "there was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made" so i can't even do that. My linux partition works fine, but now i am stuck without being able to boot into windows at all.

Comment: It is very likely you will have to reinstall Windows due to your actions.  The good news is you can access your files from within Linux in order to back them up.

Comment: Yep, i managed to get to my files and back them up, which is why i tried doing a full reset. If i reinstall windows, should i first delete the partition it is currently installed in first? Or will the installation process manage it?